# Undefined class if class is in different namespace

Tags: phpstorm

I have a yii2 project set up on phpstorm 8.0.3. My namespace structure is as follows:

```
backend\
  controllers
  models
  ...
frontend\
  controllers
  models
  ..
common\
  controllers
  models
```

I used composer on the project and have various dependancies installed in the vendor folder.

Whenever I try to use a class that is not in the same base namespace (`frontend`, `backend` or `common`), I get an undefined class error. The odd thing is the namespace of the class is in autocomplete:

[image]

Another oddity is that the undefined class error disappears for some classes if the file with the defined class is opened.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It looks like the PHPStorm cache was somehow corrupted. I ended up invalidating the cache by going to `File` -> `Invalidate Caches/Restart`. This deleted my history but fixed the undefined class issue.

Answer (score 2):

Can be helpful sometimes.

**Settings -> Directories**

Remove folders from "Excluded"

Comment: Thanks. My `vendor` folder was excluded and all classes from libraries were `undefined`.

Answer (score 1):

You must declare in `use` section nedded class or namespace. For example, if you need to use `BaseController` from `custom\controllers` namespace:

```
<?php
namespace frontend\components;

// Add this line
use common\controllers\BaseController;

class Controller extends BaseController {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have some problems with composer autoload.
Try :

```
composer update
```

Answer (score 0):

This was happening to me because of my PHP language settings. I found this out by taking out the namespace in one of my classes.  The error changed to "Scalar types are only available in PHP 7".

Go to `File -> Settings -> Language & Frameworks -> PHP`.  Change the `PHP language level` to language version 7 or greater.

Edit:
After doing that, `Insert -> Getters and Setters` was intermittently generating functions and comments as `mixed` instead of `string`.  I don't know why this happened but I recreated all my fields manually and that fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had to reset my PHPstorm to fix the issue of "Class not found".

```
File > Manage IDE Settings > Restore Default Settings...
```

Be carreful, it rests everything, but it also offers you to back up your current settings. After that, all has been hard reseted and it now works again.

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want to clear history you can copy your project directory with slightly different name, delete .idea from copy directory and open it up.